# Wrong/Different values from $area and Group Stats

Tags: area, qgis-3, otf

As mentioned in other questions there seems to be a problem with $area when OTF  is enabled. In QGIS3 it can not be disabled

My project hast EPSG 31255, some layers area 31255 some have different crs.
When i calculate the area in 31255 layers via $area in fc the results are different from groupstats.
When I open a whole new project and load only the layers in 31255, do $area it seems to work, I get the same result like from Groupstat before.

Is there workaround/solution for a existing project (e.g. not open a seperate project, doing $ area, closing, open again in other project...) as OTF can not be disabled?

Comment: seems the ellipsoid was the problem. So there were three possiblie outcomes: ellipsoid wgs84 or bessel and cartesian!? If you copy your comment into answer, I would mark this question as solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify which ellipsoid is set in `Project Properties | General | Measurements`. EPSG:31255 uses Bessel 1841. `$area` uses that value from the project properties to do the calculation. OTF projection changes the project properties so the ellipsoid will change accordingly. That's normal behavior.